# drmemory crashes when attempting to run my program (written in c)

Tags: c, mingw, dr-memory

drmemory is crashing with the following error:

```
<Invalid opcode encountered>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtCreateProcess due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dd6f5>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtCreateProcessEx due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dca05>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtCreateUserProcess due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dd8d5>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtCreateThread due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dca25>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtCreateThreadEx due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dd7f5>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtAllocateVirtualMemory due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dc365>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtFreeVirtualMemory due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dc425>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtProtectVirtualMemory due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dca65>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtMapViewOfSection due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dc565>
<intercept_syscall_wrapper: not hooking NtUnmapViewOfSection due to conflict @0x00007ff8bc1dc5a5>
~~Dr.M~~ ASSERT FAILURE (thread 51404): ..\..\drmemory\syscall_windows.c:151: opc_is_in_syscall_wrapper(opc) (unknown system call sequence)
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xffffffff
```

when attempting to run a c program compiled on mingw64 in MSYS2 with the following gcc flags:

```
-DCURL_STATICLIB -g -static -static-libgcc -Wall -I$(INCLUDE) -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lcrypt32 -lws2_32 -lWldap32 -lshlwapi
```

It does seem to be something about my program, since it does not crash for other programs.
I also tried a program with the same compilation flags but with no code to run, and it still crashes

So I'm thinking it dislikes something I am linking with.

Comment: What happens if you drop static linking?

Comment: No difference - and drmemory recommends static linking anyway

Comment: _So I'm thinking it dislikes something I am linking with_, it may be a library that is not perfectly  [ELF or COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) compatible

Comment: Which is odd, I'm not exactly linking some really obscure stuff... I compiled openssl and curl MySQL, but I did it on the same compiler

Comment: Crashes even with no libraries linked, and no code, eg, compiling with just gcc -g